# some javafx packages cannot be found (like "table")

Tags: javafx-2

I tried to start working with Netbeans with java7 and javafx for some GUI project.
Unfortunately, when try to run code I found in the following link (for creating table),
the Netbeans doesn't find some packages (attached!)
I already download the newest Netbean and the newest JavaFX with java 7 from the link below.

Does any one know how can I create those tables?

The download link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html

I copied the code from:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/hello_javafx_2_a_tableview

and the following packages cannot be found:

```
import javafx.application.Launcher;

import javafx.collections.Sequence;

import javafx.scene.control.table.TableColumn;

import javafx.scene.control.table.TableView;

import javafx.scene.control.table.model.SequenceTableModel;
```

Thank you,
Aviad

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't use `JavaFX` NB project. Try next: `File->New Project->JavaFX/JavaFX Application`. Then copy your files to this project.

Comment: in this case open `Project Properties / Libraries` and check your `Java Platform`. It should be `Default JavaFX Platform`. If you don't have such platform try to download and reinstall JavaFX SDK from javafx.com

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to uninstall java, netbeans and then reinstall java, netbeans in that order. Netbeans has issues updating itself. I had the same issue when updating to javafx 2.2.